# can allow datetime num when edit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I encounter a problem with a situation.
That is I define a `datetime` attribute in the model with entity and allow null.
Like this

```
class T_NAME 
[key] int key 
 Datetime F_DATE  
 string F_NAME
```

And I use a default view with this Model to create.
I intend to  add this record first and modify the date later but it displays that the field is required (I allow `null @database`).

How can I do in this?
Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Property to be `nullable`

```
public class T_Name
{
  [Key]
  public int Key { set;get;}
  public DateTime? F_Date { set;get;}
  public string F_Name { set;get;}
}
```